# Сервер сборки пакетов

Tags: package, c++, linux

Хочу написать сервер для сборки пакетов. Так же он должен создавать и поддерживать репозитарии. На данный момент для RedHat и компании, Gentoo и Denbian.

Не очень представляю внутреннюю структуру. И хотел бы посоветоваться и послушать чужие идеи. И по ходу дела понять, как я хочу ее сделать.

Во всей задаче даже не требуется лезть в понимание, что такое спецификация или пакет. Они представляются набором из названия пакета и данных. Эта задача по организации данных.

У сервера две задачи: репозитарии и сборка.

1. Нужны пользователи, создаем для них таблицу в БД. Но вот вопрос, где хранить их права доступа и сколько будет разных прав?
2. Исходники, спецификации, пакеты, им тоже по таблице в БД. И опять вопрос с правами пользователей.
3. Процесс сборки. Я передаю на сервер спецификацию, он должен собрать по ней пакеты под разные линуксы и сложить в репозитарии. Как это все организовать?

Технические вопросы:

1. Про генерацию файлов репозитариев я пока молчу.
2. Какой протокол использовать для общения с сервером? Для передачи пакетов и запуска заданий. Это должен быть командный протокол.
3. Должен ли в программе запускаться HTTP сервер или пусть запускается отдельно какой-нибудь httpd и через скрипты общается с моим.

Плюс вопросы:

1. Связи, пакетов, исходников, спецификаций. Чтобы можно было открыть в браузере страничку пакета и увидеть с чем он связан.

Вопросы из разряда фантастики:

1. Пространства. Например для поднятия нескольких серверов в одном. Если делать, то сразу, а не потом.

Вот как-то так. Скорее запутанно, но по ходу написания вопроса прояснились некоторые мысли. Надеюсь дойдет до обсуждения и прояснится еще больше мыслей.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужны пользователи, создаем для них таблицу в БД. Но вот вопрос, где хранить их права доступа и сколько будет разных прав?

Сколько нужно прав... сложный вопрос. Ну как минимум админ/не админ, право на удаление пакетов, право на добавление. Обычно часть свойств можно сохранить в таблице с именами пользователей. Для всего другого заводим две таблицы. В первой список названий различных прав, а в второй - id пользователя, id права и значение. Единственная проблема - нужно будет придумать, как разделить тип поля для хранения значения.

Но можно по другом. Эти дополнительные права хранить в виде json строки. Достаточно гибко.

> Процесс сборки. Я передаю на сервер спецификацию, он должен собрать по ней пакеты под разные линуксы и сложить в репозитарии. Как это все организовать?

Так как процесс сборки обычно не очень быстрый, то делают так. Заводится таблица заданий. Сервер в нее записывает задания. Другой сервер, который занимается сборкой, вычитывает задания и потихоньку исполняет. Исполнив - записывает в таблицу результат исполнения.

> Какой протокол использовать для общения с сервером? Для передачи пакетов и запуска заданий. Это должен быть командный протокол.

Сами и ответили на свой вопрос. Хотя я бы для начала взял обычный http.

> Должен ли в программе запускаться HTTP сервер или пусть запускается отдельно какой-нибудь httpd и через скрипты общается с моим.

На первых порах я бы это вообще на php|perl|python + apache + mysql собрал на посмотреть. Если выясниться, что скорости не хватает, тогда уже нужно смотреть детальнее.

> Связи, пакетов, исходников, спецификаций. Чтобы можно было открыть в браузере страничку пакета и увидеть с чем он связан.

а в чем то собственно вопрос? как нарисовать или как распарсить?

> Пространства. Например для поднятия нескольких серверов в одном. Если делать, то сразу, а не потом.

точно с области фантастики. Кто мешает писать так, что бы все настраивалось и не использовало "глобальных переменных" (в том числе файлов, с определенными именами, константные номера портов для подключения).

Answer (score 1):

А можно вопросик? Зачем это нужно, когда уже есть готовые Build Service? Регистрируйся, закачивай исходники и погнали...

https://build.opensuse.org/
https://launchpad.net/
и пр.

Если же не нравятся уже существующие сервера, то существуют программные продукты, позволяющие создать свою BUILD-систему. Например, можно спокойно скачать, изучить и развернуть у себя [OpenBuildService](http://openbuildservice.org/download/), использующийся на сайте OpenSUSE

Comment: Мне проще написать, чем разбираться в чужом. К тому же у меня конкретные задачи. В принципе существует возможность, что прикручу какой-нибудь сервер сборки. Хотя достаточно трех линуксов в виртуальных машинах.